# Encountered indoor level with missing enclosing_building field

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

After the May 2015 update of Google map, I am getting the following warning:

Encountered indoor level with missing enclosing_building field: 0x80c2bbbd1891186b:0xf16df7f729eb35d6

Any one else encountered this?

Comment: I see this, too. Started today as far as I know.

Comment: i also get this error from previous two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind disabling indoor maps, that's one way to get the error message to go away:

```
GMSMapView *mapView_;
mapView_.indoorEnabled = NO;
```

See [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map).

Otherwise, I'd assume the error is due to bad data from the google map servers and that they'll fix it soon.